# Want to pass two properties in bean write in java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

**Button Click**

```
onclick="javascriptFunction('<bean:write name="bank" property="accountNumber" />')" >Trk #</a>.
```

we are sending one parameter which I am fetching in javascript and using the same variable. like

```
function javascriptFunction(accountNumber) {
    var popUrl ='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Report.do?methodName=javascriptFunction&AC='+accountNumber;
```

Here,  I want to pass second parameter as well.. can anyone please suggest.

Comment: could you please provide your java code as well?

Comment: In java i am only getting the property and using it only. 
This accountNumber is also a property which is in JSP. i am sending this parameter on button click and fetching it through java script..

Comment: Could you try request.getParameter("AC"); and see what happen?

Comment: sir, i am getting value in java by request.getParameter.
however, i am trying to get value in javascript.

current scenario is i am sending accountNumber , i need to send phoneNumber as well.. 
I hope it clears your doubt